# Is a non-Jew permitted to light the Chanukah Candles

Tags: gentiles, chanuka, candle-lighting

Are there any halachic rules concerning the lighting of the Chanukah Candles by a non-Jew/gentile.

Comment: How would a non-Jew signify that these are Channukah candles? Is the question about saying a bracha or just lighting a random candelabrum?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48989/discussion-on-question-by-yerucham-david-ben-mordecai-is-a-non-jew-permitted-to).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [dinonline.org](http://dinonline.org/2011/12/26/non-jew-for-chanukah-candles/)

> Can a goy light the Chanukah candles?
>
> Answer:
>
> A non-Jew cannot light the Chanukah candles (on behalf of a Jew),
>   because he is not obligated in performing the mitzvah.
>
> He can light candles for himself, but it stands to reason that even
>   the Rambam, who writes that a non-Jew who performs a mitzvah receives
>   reward for so doing, might admit that this premise is weaker in regard
>   to rabbinic mitzvos, which the Sages only intended for Jews.

Comment: I am not sure why we should be more sure that rabbinic laws addressed to Jews are less appropriate for non-Jews, than biblical laws addressed to Jews.

Comment: @mevaqesh Possibly because rabbis make laws specifically for Jews and as far as I know, there are no Rabbinical laws applying to B'nai Noach.

Comment: `on behalf of a Jew` is the point of this answer but this point itself is absent in the questio.  Indeed the answer is accepted.  I don't understand.

Comment: @kouty I, as well as several others, agree with you. There's a chat session, that you can follow from the link in one of the comments. Make of it what you can - for me, it was a bit too much "chat"-er ;-) My answer addresses both possibilities.

Comment: @DanF Please can you provide a source.